# Can I take duty free alcohol from my initial departure point between terminals at London Heathrow (LHR)?

Tags: lhr, duty-free, connecting-flights

I'm changing planes at LHR soon. My incoming flight arrives at T3, and my departing flight is from T5.  If I bring duty-free alcohol in my hand luggage from my initial airport of departure, will it be confiscated when transferring terminals at London Heathrow?

Comment: Airport shop cashiers ask if you have a connecting flight, if so they put your purchases into a sealed clear plastic bag. Such bags are allowed through connecting flight security.

Comment: If nothing else, you'll probably fall foul of the limitations on the amount of liquid you can have in your hand luggage.

Answer (score 4):

From my personal experience: No it is not possible because of security checks at T5.

This experience is a few years old, but security rules became more strict the last years on not more relaxed - so I won't assume they abandoned this security check.

Comment: +1 Every time I've connected via LHR I've had to go through a security screening.

Comment: Thank you @Kris , so apparently it did not change

Comment: You should be able to take anything in a sealed duty free bag through security, notwithstanding the liquids requirements. (They're likely to open the bag and will offer to re-seal it if you have another onwards connection.)

Answer (score 4):

When you buy duty free it is in a sealed bag.
As long as it remains in this sealed bag it should be fine unless there are some specific extra checks at Heathrow that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Thats the problem. If there is a securtiy check (and there used to be one), your alcohol gets confiscated.

Comment: Airport shop cashiers ask if you have a connecting flight, if so they put your purchases into a sealed clear plastic bag. Such bags are allowed through connecting gflight security.

Comment: Note that you won't get sealed bags everywhere; e.g., some places in east Asia, AIUI, basically only have normal shopping bags.

Comment: I have seen many warnings that the sealed bags are only for the airport where you buy the liquids, not ones farther down the travel.

Comment: @Gnusper Your comment specifically implies that alcohol in a sealed duty-free bag from e.g. a US airport will get confiscated at Heathrow, which has not been the case for a long time. Perhaps you can link to reliable information on a more recent change, though?

Comment: I don't know about Heathrow specifically but I can definitely say that I have transferred flights that involved going through extra security and kept my duty free  (it was IIRC at Frankfurt)